# How to display length of Array in for loop?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display length of array in my html code. Array list contains another array list so i have to display the length of inner array list while outer array iterating

This is my html code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 cols" *ngFor="let productMapper of printProducts">
            <md-card>
                <div (click)=" gotoLink(productMapper)">
                    <div class="text-center img-wrapper">
                        <img [src]="productMapper.product.imagePath" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    <div class="text-center divider_text" title="{{productMapper.product.productName}}">
                        <span> {{productMapper.product.productName}} </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="starRatingBlock text-center" (click)="viewComments($event);">
                    <span class="commentsBlock">
                        <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"> {{productMapper.surveyData.length}}</i>
                    </span>
               </div>
         <md-card>
  </div>
```

i tried this but not working : {{productMapper.surveyData.length}}

Comment: It should work. Did you make sure that `productMapper.surveyData` is an Array?

Comment: What does `but not working` mean?

Comment: surveyData should be the inner array. if so it should work. Please add more code and provide example of your data

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 2):

Set `aria-hidden` property to `false`

```
<i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="false"> {{productMapper.surveyData.length}}</i>
```

Comment: Take a look here [link](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/)